# Distribution of bootstrap and central limit theorem

Tags: normal-distribution, bootstrap, central-limit-theorem

Let's take a simple example: we have 100000 observations, and we want to estimate the mean.

In theory, the distribution of the estimator is a normal distribution according to the Central limit theorem.

We can also use bootstraping to estimate the distribution of the mean estimation: we resample lots of times, then we get a distribution.

Now, my question is: is the normal distribution a good approximation for the bootstrap distribution?

Comment: Be careful with assumptions: The distribution of the mean of a sample of size $n=100$ from a population with mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma$ has $E(\bar X) = \mu$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$ but the distribution is exactly normal only if the population is normal. If the population is exponential then $\bar X$ has a gamma dist'n with shape param $100,$ which is _not_ the same as normal.  // In bootstrap re-sampling (samples of size $n=100$ _with replacement_ from the 
main sample will tend to have re-sample means about the same as the mean of the main sample, with appropriate variation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I am talking about the distribution of the mean estimator and not the distribution of the sample. So with resampling, to calculate the mean, you are saying in theory, the distribution will be impacted by the distribution of the sample?

Comment: Because there are many different ways to estimate a mean and many different ways to bootstrap, please give us the details, because this question otherwise has multiple different correct answers. For instance, if you are using any nonrandomized estimator and the usual nonparametric bootstrap, obviously the bootstrap distribution cannot be Normal, because it can have only a finite number of distinct values.  But in other cases the bootstrap distribution will be Normal.

Comment: thank you whuber, do you have some documentation about bootstrap methods ? Thank you. With nonparametric bootstrap, if the number of observation is huge, is the normal distribution a good approximation?

Comment: For documentation, Efron's Introduction to the Bootstrap is hard to beat.  For the nonparametric bootstrap, the distribution will depend on what estimator of the mean you are using as well as on the dataset. After all, if you use the sample mean to estimate the mean and if the dataset has a single huge outlier, the bootstrap distribution of the sample mean will be clearly non-Normal.

Comment: can comments receive the bounty?

Comment: I would love to if it is possible. whuber